# Is there a way to show currently loaded drivers in Vista 64 bit?

Tags: windows-vista, drivers

Is there a way to show currently loaded drivers in Vista 64 bit without having to reboot and do a logged boot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an article form the How-To geek that shows how to view currently installed drivers:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/view-the-list-of-installed-drivers-the-easy-way/

The article talks about using a utility called DriverView. It allows you to view your currently installed drivers and even to export data on them to text files.

Comment: Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) and go to the Services tab.
Check for the entries with type = "KernelDriver".